# Как установить пакет mysql-udf-ipv6_0.4_amd64.deb который добавляет в MySQL новую функцию?

Tags: mysql, sql

Как установить пакет mysql-udf-ipv6_0.4_amd64.deb который добавляет в MySQL новую функцию `INET6_ATON`, для старых версий?

Comment: `dpkg -i mysql-udf-ipv6_0.4_amd64.deb` пробовали?

Comment: https://bitbucket.org/watchmouse/mysql-udf-ipv6 раздел INSTALLATION. а вообще, если возможно - обновитесь до MySQL 5.6.3 и отпадет надобность в бубен стучать :-)

Comment: @cache Босюь потерять данные. Хоть я и дамп сделал. Всё равно страшно .

Comment: @Slava Semushin Спасибо. Попробую.